# How can I repoint my domain? DNS/MX etc

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns, mx

I've searched the questions here, but have found nothing that gives me the assurance I require.

My situation:

- I have a domain registered with Network Solutions, linked to hosting on NetSol
- I have hosting at GoDaddy
- I wish to have the domain registered with NetSol point to the hosting at GoDaddy
- I also have an external mailserver that must be pointed at to handle all mail requests (MX?)

My question is how to I go about executing the above? Do I go into my Network Solutions account and change the DNS settings for the domain in question, changing the NS addresses to GoDaddy, and the MX addresses to my mail server? If this is correct, how would I then set the folder on GoDaddy that the domain points to, do I do this via my GoDaddy account?

Apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere, I just require absolute clarity as this is for a fairly sensitive website change- and apologies for my ignorance on the matter!

Comment: I've rolled back the question to use the names of the companies you're using, exactly as Su' suggested, because I had to read it three times to understand it with the (A)/(B) notation you'd used. (I've also answered your question below.) Hope that's OK.

Comment: Thats fine- I initially used the A/B designations to make it more abstract and not just referencing the specific service providers- to get an idea for the general requisites as opposed to the specific approach with NS/GoDaddy

Comment: I first thought about answering the question using your A/B notation, or by saying 'change your A record at the place you registered your domain to point to the place you're now hosting the site at', but both options felt less clear than just naming the companies. Hopefully others who come across this question will substitute 'GoDaddy' for their new web host and 'Network Solutions' for their domain registrar to apply domain repointing to their own situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I go into my Network Solutions account and change the DNS settings for the domain in question, changing the NS addresses to the goDaddy host, and the MX addresses to my mail server?

Change your [A records](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/a-records-ip-addresses/) or [CNAME records](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/cname-records-host-aliases/) to point to the GoDaddy server IP address or hostname, and your [MX records](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/mx-records-mail-servers/) to point to the mailserver. (You should be able to find the GoDaddy server IP address or hostname in your hosting control panel.)

> If this is correct, how would I then set the folder on my host (B) that the domain (A) points to, do I do this via my goDaddy account?

You need to add the domain in your GoDaddy control panel. This differs depending on which hosting package you have with them. See [Managing Your Hosting Account Domains](http://help.godaddy.com/article/4688) from their help pages. Be sure to set up this new domain before changing your DNS records with Network Solutions so that the account and folder exists when traffic starts to arrive at GoDaddy's servers.

Comment: Thanks- the switch is due for tomorrow so will rate then :)